# Wordpress permalink rewrite for custom taxonomy and post type that uses parent and child terms hierarchy in URLs

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have registered a custom taxonomy and post type to handle the display of photo galleries on my website. I am needing to setup the permalinks to look like this: domain.com/photos/region/country/location or domain.com/photos/country/location depending on the selected terms for each post type. The region and country terms would be dependent on if the parent terms are **Canada**, **United States**, or **World**.

An example:

- Canada (parent term)

  - Alberta (child term)
- United States (parent term)

  - Arizona (child term)
- World (parent term)

  - France (child term)

**Register taxonomy code**

```
register_taxonomy( 'photo_galleries', array( 'photos' ),
  array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
      'slug' => 'galleries',
      'with_front' => false
    ),
));
```

**Custom post type arguments**

```
$args = array(
  'supports' => $supports,
  'labels' => $labels,
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'public' => true,
  'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => 'photos',
    'with_front' => false
  ),
  'menu_position' => 5,
  'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-gallery',
  'has_archive' => true,
);
register_post_type( 'photos', $args );
```

**Galleries post_type_link function**

```
function galleries_post_type_link( $url, $post ) {
  if ( $post->post_type == 'photos' ) {
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->id, 'photo_galleries' );
    $term = $terms[0]->slug;
    $url = str_replace('photos/', 'photos/' . $term . '/', $url);
  }
  return $url;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'galleries_post_type_link', 10, 4);
```

Right now this code is showing the following permalink structure in the admin panel custom post editor: **domain.com/photos/france/bordeaux/**. This post has a parent term of **World** and a child term of **France**. The term **France** has been set to primary, but making **World** the primary term has no effect on the permalink. As you can see, France is only being used in the permalink.

I have tried the following custom permalink structures with no success: `/%category%/%postname%/` and `/%postname%/`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wordpress permalinks are pretty sensitive, do your due diligence before pushing to live.

You don not need to change the permalink in the settings, leave it to `/%postname%/`.

In your `function.php`, let's add the following just to make that when we mess with the permalinks they actually updates.

```php
/**
* Remove rewrite rules and then recreate rewrite rules.
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/
* Should be removed before pushing to live.
*/
flush_rewrite_rules();
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'flush_rewrite_rules' );
```

Let's create a custom post type called `Photos` and a custom taxonomies called `Locations`.

```php
/**
* Register question custom post type.
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/
*/
add_action( 'init', 'wp_so66575072_custom_post_type' );
function wp_so66575072_custom_post_type() {
    $args = [
        'label' => 'Photos',
        'labels' => [ 
            'singular_name' => 'Photo', 
        ],
        'public' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true, //Enable Gutenberg
        'menu_position' => -1,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-editor-quote',
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'taxonomies' => [ 'locations', ],
        'has_archive' => true,
        'delete_with_user' => false,
        'rewrite' => [
            'slug' => 'photos/%locations%',
        ],
    ];
    register_post_type( 'photos', $args );
};

/**
* Register locations custom taxonomy.
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/
*/
add_action( 'init', 'wp_so66575072_custom_taxonomy' );
function wp_so66575072_custom_taxonomy() {
    $args = [
        'labels' => [
            'name' => 'Locations',
            'singular_name' => 'Location' 
        ],
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true, //Enable Gutenberg
        'rewrite' => [
            'slug' => 'locations',
            'hierarchical' => true,
        ],
    ];
    register_taxonomy( 'locations', [ 'photos' ], $args );
};
```

We need to replace our custom taxonomy handle %location% by our terms.

```php
/**
* Replace custom taxonomy permalink handle.
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/
*/
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wp_so66575072_post_type_link' );
function wp_so66575072_post_type_link( $post_link ) {
    $taxonomy = 'locations';
    //@link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy );
    $slug = [];
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        //@link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title_with_dashes/
        if ( $term->parent == 0 ) {
            array_unshift( $slug, sanitize_title_with_dashes( $term->name ) );
        } else {
            array_push( $slug, sanitize_title_with_dashes( $term->name ) );
        };
    };
    if ( ! empty( $slug ) ) {
        return str_replace( '%' . $taxonomy . '%' , join( '/', $slug ) , $post_link );
    }
    return $post_link;  
};
```

Comment: Is there an additional filter required to have the permalinks properly rewritten when outputted by plugins like Advanced Custom Fields. I am using the Post Object field to return the permalink for use on related story pages. The links are being outputted like this: **http://domain/photos/%locations%/bordeaux/.

Comment: I nearly never use plugins, so I couldn't say sorry, it's working on my end, that's the only thing I can tell you.

Comment: No worries. The same issue is occurring when I try and add a menu item for a custom post type item, though after first visit to the URL, the menu item updates to the corrected filtered URL (domain/photos/world/france/bordeaux). Is this a core WordPress issue?

Comment: Well we're adding a behaviour that isn't native to Wordpress. Filtering is supposed to be done on the taxonomy side. The behaviour isn't native because permalinks needs to be protected. Imagine, If you remove a term from a taxonomy, all posts using that taxonomy for permalink would register a 404. That's why, for example, ecommerce stores don't display categories in there permalinks for products. I think you should think it over.

Comment: From experience I can tell you that messing with permalinks is never a good idea. There is a reason Wordpress did it this way, and I can assure you it's the best and safest way. If you worry about some mystic SEO benefits, just use a custom breadcrumb which will have the same effect overall. Pretty permalinks are mainly for users, a nice breadcrumb with the custom post type taxonomies will have the same effect. You won't get penalised SEO wised, SEO sanction don't exist, you can only go improve SEO from a development standpoint.