# How to get category/subcategory/post name in url custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-theme

I registered custom post type and I registerem custom taxonomy. I added category "Hormann" and I added subcategory "Bramy". I would like to have url in my post "mysite.com/archive_name/category/subacategory/post_name". Please help me.

Edit: I did it writed code in my file functions.php, but my code is not working properly, because displays the link after entering the category "mysite.com/archive_name/category/", but it displays the wrong link after click in the post "mysite.com/archive_name/subacategory/post_name"

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'projectcategory_permalink_structure', 10, 4);
function projectcategory_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample) {
    if (false !== strpos($post_link, '%kategorie_dladomu%')) {
        $projectscategory_type_term = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'kategorie_dladomu');
        $slug = [];
        foreach ( $projectscategory_type_term as $project ){
            if ( $project->parent == 0 ) {
                array_unshift( $slug, sanitize_title_with_dashes( $project->name ) );
            } else {
                array_push( $slug, sanitize_title_with_dashes( $project->name ) );
            }
            if ( ! empty( $slug ) ) {
                return str_replace( '%kategorie_dladomu%' , join( '/', $slug ) , $post_link );
            }
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

Comment: Answered this last week. I'm pretty sure this is the exact same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66576063/3645650

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress permalink rewrite for custom taxonomy and post type that uses parent and child terms hierarchy in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66575072/wordpress-permalink-rewrite-for-custom-taxonomy-and-post-type-that-uses-parent-a)

Comment: I checked in your link and this code not working, beacuse appears error " Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ". Foreach doesn`t check array with function get_the_terms().